# ImportError: cannot import name 'MockV3Aggregator' from 'brownie'

Tags: solidity, blockchain, brownie, chainlink

I am learning Solidity at the moment and I am facing an error when trying to use MockV3Aggregator:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MockV3Aggregator' from 'brownie'
```

Here is my bronwie-config.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - "@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1"
      - "@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@3.4.0"
networks:
  default: development
  development:
    keyhash: "0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc"
    fee: 100000000000000000
  mainnet-fork:
    eth_usd_price_feed: "0x5f4ec3df9cbd43714fe2740f5e3616155c5b8419"
  rinkeby:
    vrf_coordinator: "0x6168499c0cFfCaCD319c818142124B7A15E857ab"
    eth_usd_price_feed: "0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e"
    link_token: "0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709"
    keyhash: "0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc"
    fee: 100000000000000000
    verify:
wallets:
  from_key: ${PRIVATE_KEY}
```

And here is where I am trying to access the MockV3Aggregator:

```
from brownie import (
    Contract,
    network,
    config,
    accounts,
    MockV3Aggregator,
    VRFCoordinatorMock,
    LinkToken,
)


FORKED_LOCAL_ENVIRONMENTS = ["mainnet-fork"]
LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS = ["development", "ganache-local"]


DECIMALS = 8
STARTING_PRICE = 200000000000


def get_accounts(index=None, id=None):
    if index:
        return accounts[index]
    if id:
        return accounts.load(id)
    if (
        network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS
        or network.show_active() in FORKED_LOCAL_ENVIRONMENTS
    ):
        return accounts[0]

    return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])


contract_to_mock = {
    "eth_usd_price_feed": MockV3Aggregator,
    "v3_aggregator": VRFCoordinatorMock,
    "link_token": LinkToken,
}


def get_contract(contract_name):
    """
    This function will grab the contract addresses from the brownie
    config if defined, otherwise it will deploy a mock version of
    that contract and return that mock contract.

        Args:
            contract_name (string)
        Returns:
            brownie.network.contract.projectContract: The most recently
            deployed version of this contract.
            MockV3Aggregator[-1]

    """

    contract_type = contract_to_mock[contract_name]
    if network.show_active() in LOCAL_BLOCKCHAIN_ENVIRONMENTS:
        if len(contract_type <= 0):
            deploy_mocks()
        contract = contract_type[-1]
    else:
        contract_address = config["networks"][network.show_active()][contract_name]
        # address
        # ABI
        contract = Contract.from_abi(
            contract_type._name, contract_address, contract_type.abi
        )
        return contract


def deploy_mocks():
    account = get_accounts()
    MockV3Aggregator.deploy(DECIMALS, STARTING_PRICE, {"from": account})
    link_token = LinkToken.deploy({"from": account})
    VRFCoordinatorMock.deploy(link_token.address, {"from": account})
    print("Mocks deployed...")
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add that contract to your `contracts` folder. See the [`chainlink-mix`](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-mix/tree/main/contracts/test) for reference.

Just make a contract in your contracts folder like so:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV2V3Interface.sol";

/**
 * @title MockV3Aggregator
 * @notice Based on the FluxAggregator contract
 * @notice Use this contract when you need to test
 * other contract's ability to read data from an
 * aggregator contract, but how the aggregator got
 * its answer is unimportant
 */
contract MockV3Aggregator is AggregatorV2V3Interface {
  uint256 constant public override version = 0;

  uint8 public override decimals;
  int256 public override latestAnswer;
  uint256 public override latestTimestamp;
  uint256 public override latestRound;

  mapping(uint256 => int256) public override getAnswer;
  mapping(uint256 => uint256) public override getTimestamp;
  mapping(uint256 => uint256) private getStartedAt;

  constructor(
    uint8 _decimals,
    int256 _initialAnswer
  ) public {
    decimals = _decimals;
    updateAnswer(_initialAnswer);
  }

  function updateAnswer(
    int256 _answer
  ) public {
    latestAnswer = _answer;
    latestTimestamp = block.timestamp;
    latestRound++;
    getAnswer[latestRound] = _answer;
    getTimestamp[latestRound] = block.timestamp;
    getStartedAt[latestRound] = block.timestamp;
  }

  function updateRoundData(
    uint80 _roundId,
    int256 _answer,
    uint256 _timestamp,
    uint256 _startedAt
  ) public {
    latestRound = _roundId;
    latestAnswer = _answer;
    latestTimestamp = _timestamp;
    getAnswer[latestRound] = _answer;
    getTimestamp[latestRound] = _timestamp;
    getStartedAt[latestRound] = _startedAt;
  }

  function getRoundData(uint80 _roundId)
    external
    view
    override
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    )
  {
    return (
      _roundId,
      getAnswer[_roundId],
      getStartedAt[_roundId],
      getTimestamp[_roundId],
      _roundId
    );
  }

  function latestRoundData()
    external
    view
    override
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    )
  {
    return (
      uint80(latestRound),
      getAnswer[latestRound],
      getStartedAt[latestRound],
      getTimestamp[latestRound],
      uint80(latestRound)
    );
  }

  function description()
    external
    view
    override
    returns (string memory)
  {
    return "v0.6/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this is what you want but you can get a copy of the mockv3aggregator.sol from github (https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts/blob/main/contracts/src/v0.6/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol) and put it in the contracts/ folder. brownie will compile it and you should be able to use it. It worked in my case

EDIT: I forgot to say I installed chainlink with

```
yarn add @chainlink/contracts
```

and changed the import in the mock to local installation of chainlink

```
import "node_modules/@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV2V3Interface.sol";
```

Answer (score 0):

This [section of the Solidity course](https://youtu.be/M576WGiDBdQ?si=nZMn2DLJbgp-nQrG&t=19648) from FreeCodeCamp explains how to add the Mock contract to a `test` folder inside your `contracts` folder.

Steps:

1. Create `test` folder in `contracts` folder
2. Create a new file called `MockV3Aggregator.sol`
3. Copy the contract from the [chainlink-mix repo](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-mix/tree/main/contracts/test)
4. Run `brownie compile`